# What is 22527 in error_reporting 22527 of phpinfo

Tags: php

In my local dev env, I use PHP Version 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.2.

Now when I see error_reporting, the value is 22527.

What is 22527?

I checked http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php, but I could not find the number.

Could anyone tell me what it is?

Do I need to change it to E_ALL | E_STRICT ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An alternative is to open your `php\php.ini` file directly and find for `error_reporting`. E.g. on my system, php.ini line 535 writes `error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

Comment: Your number 22517 is a sum of some of the numbers from the constants documentation page. If you turn it into binary, you would get 0101011111111111. Means the E_STRICT, E_DEPRECATED and E_ALL are set to 0 (disabled), and all others are set to 1 (enabled).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This value is actually [bitmap mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)), a sum of constants.

So, 22527 is

```
  16384 E_USER_DEPRECATED
+
  4096  E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR
+
  etc...
```

In your case it's `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED`, it will display every error, except `E_DEPRECATED`.

PHP versions below 5.4 will also exclude `E_STRICT` errors (since `E_STRICT` is not included in `E_ALL` before that version)

Comment: Just to point that since PHP 5.4.0 `E_STRICT` is now part of `E_ALL` again

Answer (score 50):

This value is one or more of [these constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) bitwise-ored together.

[`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) usually displays the numeric value instead of the constants or shorthands used inside INI files. Here is an example to map the value back to constants:

```php
$error_reporting_value = 22527;
$constants = array(
    "E_ERROR",
    "E_WARNING",
    "E_PARSE",
    "E_NOTICE",
    "E_CORE_ERROR",
    "E_CORE_WARNING",
    "E_COMPILE_ERROR",
    "E_COMPILE_WARNING",
    "E_USER_ERROR",
    "E_USER_WARNING",
    "E_USER_NOTICE",
    "E_STRICT",
    "E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR",
    "E_DEPRECATED",
    "E_USER_DEPRECATED",
    "E_ALL"
);
$included = [];
$excluded = [];
foreach ($constants as $constant) {
    $value = constant($constant);
    if (($error_reporting_value & $value) === $value) {
        $included[] = $constant;
    } else {
        $excluded[] = $constant;
    }
}
echo "error reporting " . $error_reporting_value . PHP_EOL;
echo "includes " . implode(", ", $included) . PHP_EOL;
echo "excludes " . implode(", ", $excluded) . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
error reporting 22527
includes E_ERROR, E_WARNING, E_PARSE, E_NOTICE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, E_USER_ERROR, E_USER_WARNING, E_USER_NOTICE, E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR, E_USER_DEPRECATED
excludes E_STRICT, E_DEPRECATED, E_ALL
```

Comment: how come E_ALL is not in there?

Comment: In php.ini file I added error_reporting = E_ERROR & E_WARNING & E_PARSE & E_NOTICE & E_CORE_ERROR & E_CORE_WARNING & E_COMPILE_ERROR & E_COMPILE_WARNING & E_USER_ERROR & E_USER_WARNING & E_USER_NOTICE & E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR & E_USER_DEPRECATED and I get 
error_reporting 0

Comment: & is a bitwise operation, not a boolean operation. So you are doing something like 100 & 010 & 001, which is 000.

Comment: @SalmanA I'm sorry, I should have specified that I was responding to themis.

Answer (score 3):

NEVER use the numeric value to set your error reporting, as the [meaning of that value can change](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) but the meaning of the constants (like E_ALL, E_STRICT, etc) likely will not:

> The new error_reporting level. It takes on either a bitmask, or named constants. Using named constants is strongly encouraged to ensure compatibility for future versions. As error levels are added, the range of integers increases, **so older integer-based error levels will not always behave as expected**.

(and note that as of PHP 5.4, E_ALL now includes E_STRICT)

IF you want the strictest reporting forever and ever, you could set error_reporting to a very large number in order to guarantee(?) that [you will report all errors forever](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) :

> Using PHP Constants outside of PHP, like in httpd.conf, will have no useful meaning so in such cases the integer values are required. And since error levels will be added over time, the maximum value (for E_ALL) will likely change. So in place of E_ALL **consider using a larger value to cover all bit fields from now and well into the future, a numeric value like 2147483647** (includes all errors, not just E_ALL).

Check your php.ini for the value of error_reporting in human-readable PHP constants format. The phpinfo() function appears to always show the numeric value rather than showing the constants.

But, personally, I leave php.ini with the default values for error reporting. Instead I just put the error reporting function at the top of whatever php script I'm working on to override the defaults. e.g.:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realised 0x7FFFFFFF was prime!

Comment: But **0** will always refer to "turn everything off" even as more error reporting levels are added wouldn't it?

Comment: But `2147483647` only has 32 bits, wouldn't it break in the **future**? Why not use `-1`?

Comment: -1 would be better than a large integer, but that can break as well. Using it to denote 111111... assumes 2's compliment. ~0 will always be right, and it is more readable.

Comment: `php -i | grep error_reporting` from the command line itself reports the setting as an integer, which is how I came across the same exact integer as the original poster.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ php -i | grep error_reporting
```

> o/p is  22527

Go To
https://maximivanov.github.io/php-error-reporting-calculator/

Enter 22527 in Resulting Error Level box.

> O/p is E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED

OR

```
$arr = array_flip(array_slice(get_defined_constants(true)['Core'], 0,15));   
$needToRemove = array('E_ALL','E_STRICT','E_DEPRECATED');
$filtered = array_diff($arr, $needToRemove);
print_r($filtered);
echo array_sum(array_flip($filtered));
```

> o/p is

```
Array
(
    [1] => E_ERROR
    [4096] => E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR
    [2] => E_WARNING
    [4] => E_PARSE
    [8] => E_NOTICE
    [16] => E_CORE_ERROR
    [32] => E_CORE_WARNING
    [64] => E_COMPILE_ERROR
    [128] => E_COMPILE_WARNING
    [256] => E_USER_ERROR
    [512] => E_USER_WARNING
    [1024] => E_USER_NOTICE
    [16384] => E_USER_DEPRECATED
)
```

22527

Comment: Nice answer as it provides a way to decode int to list of const, thanks !