# global php error reporting - can I include a file to stop errors displaying?

Tags: php

Upgrading to a new server has brought a lot of PHP errors. My site has a lot of different includes, so instead of tracking down and adding `error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` Is there a better way I can remove these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your `php.ini` file and set:

```
error_reporting = 32759
```

If you're using Apache, you can also set it in `httpd.conf` or a `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value error_reporting 32759
```

The numbers are looked up from: http://php.net/errorfunc.constants

Comment: Can't find the number 32759 at this site. Where do you get this number?

Comment: Ok, I find my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678082/what-is-22527-in-error-reporting-22527-of-phpinfo

Answer (score 3):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
error_reporting(0);
```