# Show PHP errors as a string for display

Tags: php

I'm trying to find out how I would put a PHP error into a variable to display.

Similar to the `mysql_error();` I'd like to be able to have displayed the error that PHP gives?

I'm using `json_encode` to send the testing user back a value from the requested PHP page but if an error happens I can get the `mysql_error();` fine but how would I get the php error?

I've tryed `$phpError = error_reporting();` but I just get error `22527` like this [same Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678082/what-is-22527-in-error-reporting-22527-of-phpinfo). I just want to put the php error into a string to send back to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own error handler: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php 
And return a json encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an custom error handler with [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and from that point on you can do anything you want

Answer (score 0):

Check out [$php_errormsg](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.phperrormsg.php). I hope it helps.