# php info gives me error_reporting local value 4177

Tags: error-reporting, php

In `php.ini` I have changed display_errors to "OFF". Now my php info page shows me `errror_reporting` local value set to `4177` and master value is also the same. What is the meaning of this value ?

[image: PHP info]

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678082/what-is-22527-in-error-reporting-22527-of-phpinfo

Comment: The master value is the value set in php.ini, while the local value can be a different value (specified in a .htaccess file or with ini_set)